# Test Automation with Perl

Tags: perl, selenium, automated-tests, test-class

I am working on building a test automation framework with Perl and Selenium for a web-application.

I am weighing the pros and cons (with respect to maintainability of tests) of using Test::Routine v/s Test::Class . If there are people who have experience using either, can you please share your experiences ?

I am a beginner , so any links to more information concerning the benefits of either would also be greatly beneficial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the awesome beauty of the Perl community and CPAN, I found this module that I think already does what you want to implement:

[`Test::WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.33/lib/Test/WWW/Selenium.pm)